# Trouble getting windows service to start

Tags: delphi, windows-services

I'm having trouble getting a windows service to start.  Each time it runs, in the IDE, as a service, or otherwise, an error shows up in the windows event log stating:

> "The service process could not connect to the service controller."

When debugging, I can step through the `ServiceCreate` procedure, and I successful print to a log file there.  However, I have identical code (save the message string) in the `ServiceStart` or `ServiceExecute` procedures and it never appears to run.

The debugger lets me step into `Application.CreateForm`, which jumps straight to the `ServiceCreate` procedure but I cannot step into `Application.Run`.

Any ideas?

Edit: To clarify, I am debugging by starting the windows service, then attaching to the process in Delphi during a wait that I added to start up.

Edit 2: Okay, it's now letting me step into `Application.Run` and more details where ever I want.  I had turned off debug dcus.  Thought stepping through the VCL code did nothing to help me see what the problem was.  I still have no idea how `ServiceStart` or `ServiceExecute` are supposed to get called.

Comment: ServiceStart or ServiceExecute are called in response to messages sent by the service control manager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the only error message you receive? what code do you have in the initialization section of your pas files? this error is generally raised when an error is raised and your application doesn't catch it. try to log all the events from app. also, take a look into the Windows event viewer for more details related to this.

Comment: So it's working now.  I ended up starting from scratch, to make sure I caught errors as I introduced them.  (Most of the code is in a separate library, so I was just attaching it to a service application.)  The downfalls appear to have largely been me making assumptions (the working directory is NOT where the exe runs) and not catching errors at the top level.